# Link tables when one column is padded with 0's in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a database that has two tables that need to be linked, but in one table the data is padded with zeros. For example, the tables may look like this:

> CUSTOMER.CUSTNUM = 00000000123456
>
> CUSTOMERPHONE.CUSTNUM = 123456

I can't figure out how to get these tables to properly join.

What I'm trying to do now is trick Crystal Reports into specifying the Join clause by adding the following to the selection expert:

> Right ({CUSTOMER.CUSTNUM}) = {CUSTOMERPHONE.CUSTNUM}

That's not working though, and I get no records at all in my report.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal doesn't like heterogeneous joins.

Options:

- use a command object, which will give you more control over the linkage
- create a SQL Expression that performs the desired concatination; link fields in the record-selection formula
- use a subreport for the linked table
- alter the table to make the data types compatible
- create a SQL view that performs the joins

Answer (score 1):

First thing, why does CUSTOMER.CUSTNUM have leading zeros in the first place? It seems to me that it should be a NUMERIC data type instead of a VARCHAR. CUSTNUM should be consistent in all of the tables. Just a thought.

Anyway, to answer your question, you could try creating a SQL Command in Crystal to join the two tables. In the join, just use your database's function for converting from a varchar to a number. For example, in Access you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Customer`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Orders` ON `Orders`.`Numeric Customer ID` = CLng(`Customer`.`Varchar Customer ID`)
```

Answer (score 1):

If fastest performance isn't an issue, you can accomplish this using Select Expert. I think the problem is your formula.

Try changing your formula from this:

```
{CUSTOMERPHONE.CUSTNUM} = Right({CUSTOMER.CUSTNUM})
```

to this:

```
{CUSTOMERPHONE.CUSTNUM} = Right({CUSTOMER.CUSTNUM}, Length({CUSTOMERPHONE.CUSTNUM}))
```